# Implementing SSL , JAX-WS webservice on IBM Websphere Application server

Tags: ssl, websphere, jax-ws

I am trying to make SSL work on a webservices created by using IBM Websphere JAX-WS runtime for quite a while now but am unable to make it work somehow.

Need your help in resolving the problem.

These are the steps I have taken.

Its a simple Add Numbers Web service which adds two numbers and returns the output.

I deployed the webservice on WAS 7.0

the endpoint for the ws  is http://localhost:9080/WebServiceProject/AddNumbersSvc/AddNumbersSvc.wsdl

Than to configure the ssl I took the following steps:

In WAS admin console I went to: Services->Policy Sets->Application Policy Sets. Than I selected WSHTTPS default. copied it and rename it to WS SSL Policy, I dint chnage anything in it.
Next, I went to Security->SSl ceritificate and key management ->Key stores and certificates I created ServerKeyStore with a self signed certificate and ServerTrustStore with the client public key
Than,  I went to Security->SSl ceritificate and key management -> SSL Configurations and I created  a new configuration WS SSL conf set the trust store as ServerTrustStore and Keystore  as ServerKeyStore
Next, I went to QOP setting of WS SSL conf. There I set client authentication as required , protocol as ssl and rest all default.
Than, I went to Services->Policy Sets->General provider policy set bindings.  Than I selected WSHTTPS default. copied it and rename it to WS SSL Binding. seleced it. than selected SSL transport and selected WS SSL conf as SSL settings
Finally I went to Services->Service providers. selected AddNumbers service and apllied WS SSL Policy as policy set and   WS SSL Binding as Binding.

Now when i restated the application and tried to execute the ws through 
https://localhost:9080/WebServiceProject/AddNumbersSvc/AddNumbersSvc.wsdl

i got a 404 :( and also when i triggered the ws through SOAPUi with http i got the repsonse but not with https.

Now  pls help me to figure out what i did wrong .

Comment: Will you be running apache or IHS in front of WebSphere when you deploy to your test environments and production?  I usually don't worry about SSL on my local workstation because Apache handles SSL in my other environments.

Comment: Na I am not going to run apache or IHS. The requirement is to create a two way ssl authentication between JAX-WS ws deployed on WAS 7.0 and a JAX-RPC client running on WAS 6.0

Comment: I have the same problem, can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657801/implementing-ssl-jax-ws-webservice-on-ibm-websphere-application-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web Containers listens to different ports for HTTP and HTTPS

9080 is the default port for HTTP while 9443 is the default port for HTTPS.

The URL that you have is trying to make an SSL request to an non-SSL port.

HTH
Manglu

Comment: Thanx man it worked. But is there any way to restrict the client to only https. Tight now i can call the webservice from both http://localhost:9080/WebServiceProject/AddNumbersSvc/AddNumbersSvc.wsdl and https://localhost:9443/WebServiceProject/AddNumbersSvc/AddNumbersSvc.wsdl  endpoints. I want my web service to be exposed only with https endpoint.

Comment: Multiple ways to do that. Do not allow the HTTP support on that webcontainer (this would affect all applications) hosted on that container. Alteratively, front the Web App with a Web Server and use directives in Web Server to redirect to the HTTPS for this Web App URLS.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to disable http request and enable https as shown below.

Server -> Server Types -> Application servers > select the server > Web container transport chains.
Disable WCInboundDefault.
Enable WCInboundDefaultSecure